# Does Visual Studio Code have any features that Visual Studio Community doesn't?

Tags: visual-studio-code, visual-studio-2015

This is in reference to Visual Studio Community 2015 and the original release of Visual Studio Code.

If I go ahead and use Visual Studio Community 2015, am I missing out on any features that VS Code has but which are absent from VS 2015? Or is VS Community a strict super-set of the features in VS Code?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Visual Studio (VS) and Visual Studio Code (VSCode) are completely different products. They are not real competitors.

VS is a full blown IDE coming with compilers, debuggers, libraries, project templates etc. It's running on Windows and MacOS machines only.

VSCode is a lightweight text editor  designed for coders. It supports many different file types and can be attached to compilers and debuggers but it's not coming with any compiler or library. It's running on all desktop platforms.

VSCode can be a good companion to VS when you want to maintain C# or C++ projects.
If you want to write JavaScript, TypeScript, HTML, PHP files etc. VSCode can  work as your one and only code editor.